# script run by launchd not evaluating env variables

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, launchd

```
#!/bin/sh

SharePath=$(dscl /Search -read /Users/$USER OriginalHomeDirectory | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g'| awk -F'/' '{ print substr($0, index($0, $4))}')

prefix='/Volumes/'

LocalMountPoint=$prefix$SharePath

ln -s $LocalMountPoint "/Users/$USER/Desktop/P Drive"
```

So I have this script when run from bash works perfectly. When setting it as a LaunchAgent it fails because it evaluates "/Users/$USER/Desktop/P Drive" as "/Users//Desktop/P Drive" and says the file doesn't exist. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the LaunchAgent plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.user.loginscript2</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <string>/Library/pdrive.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript2.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript2.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It is most likely failing at line 3 since it is trying to evaluate $USER as well, but the logs don't show me that error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by modifying the .plist as such

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.user.loginscript2</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
          <string>sh</string>
          <string>-c</string>
          <string>/Library/pdrive.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript2.err</string>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/tmp/com.user.loginscript2.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```